# Is that possible to show the ball (0,$\epsilon$) contains any point other than 0 itself?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am really confused about this part .
So Let's say in a space which is just R, and the metric is the norm metric.

Comment: In discrete metric, no, there need not be any other point.

Comment: What do you mean with "the ball $(0,\epsilon)$"?

Comment: @drhab, It means a spher/circle/interval, depends on what space you choose, which centers at 0 and with radius $\epsilon$, or a radius with  infinitely small.

Comment: @geetha290krm, so in which metric it will contain another point?

Comment: As stated, there is not enough context to answer this question. Is this ball defined in the real numbers with the standard distance metric? Is $\epsilon$ an arbitrary positive real number? If so, then the ball does contain other points, e.g. $\epsilon/2$. However, there is *no* non-zero point which is in *every* such ball, i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: If the metric is given by a norm then there are other points in the ball.

Comment: $0+\epsilon=\epsilon.$

Comment: How do you prove $0=0+\epsilon$???

Comment: @TongSu I assume you know that the ball contains points but need a proof. Is that correct? If so, use the definition of open ball and your knowledge of inequalities to prove, as others have pointed out, that $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is in the ball.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb R$, with the standard metric, and assuming that $\epsilon > 0$, the ball $B(0,\epsilon)$ contains infinitely many points. This is because the ball is equal to the interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

For example, it contains the point $\frac\epsilon2$.